# Calculating the Sub Differential Through Proximal Operator / Mapping

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

I was wondering if it was possible to characterize the elements in a subdifferential of a seminorm, $\partial \|\cdot\|$, through means of the proximal mapping. I know of therelation

$$u = Prox_f (v) \Leftrightarrow v - u \in \partial f (u), $$

can this be exploited to easily calculate the subdifferential? In particular, I am trying to calculate the expression

$$ \inf_{z \in \partial f} \|g - \tau z \|_2^2$$

where $g \sim N(0,1)$ is a standard normal vector and $\tau \in \mathbb{R}$. For this however I need to make clear the structure of the subdifferential in question, and I am searching for the easiest way to do that. I do know the proximal operators of the seminorms in question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not want to write a definitive answer since there might be a trick I am not aware of, but it seems impossible. The subdifferential at $u$ is a set, but the proximal mapping at $u$ is a unique point. I do not believe it is possible to characterize the entire subdifferential using a point. And if it is possible to somehow use the proximal mapping, I believe it would require the proximal mapping at an infinite amount of points which belong to some set which is still hard to compute, and thus is of no practical value.

Comment: I thought as much, thanks for clarifying it!

Comment: @AlexShtof, I think the OP would take even unique item from the set.